# Magento 2: Allow Arabic string in "letters-only" validation

Tags: magento2.2.6, validation, customer-registration

I'am working on the Magento store that have **Arabic language** store and **English language store**.

I have added the **"letters-only"** validation on firstName input field on registration page and when I check this validation on English version its working fine, but in Arabic version validation not working.

**"Letters only"** validation not accept Arabic string.

I'm trying below rules one by one but no luck:-

```
//return this.optional(element) || !/^[0-9_]+$/i.test(value);
return this.optional(element) || /^[\p{Arabic}a-zA-Z\- .ـ]+$/i.test(value);             
return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z\-+,()/'\s\p{Arabic}]+$/i.test(value);
return this.optional(element) || /^[\s\p{Arabic}]+$/i.test(value);
```

Please suggest any solution to get rid this issue So in Arabic version user can add their information.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

To validate the Arabic language characters you have to use the Unicode.

```
var unicode=e.charCode? e.charCode : e.keyCode
```

You can check the Example on GIT from [here](https://gist.github.com/muzfr7/faf97fccf267504916a5f557b166118d).

Answer (score 0):

After spent more time on this, I get the solution to fix this issue.

Copy the validation.js file from below path:

```
lib\web\mage\validation.js
```

put in below directory:

```
**app\design\frontend\venorName\themename\web\mage\validation.js**


'letters-only': [
            function (value, element) {
                return this.optional(element) || /^[a-zA-Z \u0600-\u06ff]+$/i.test(value);              
            },
            $.mage.__('Letters only please')
        ],
```

After above changes 'letters-only' validation working well in Arabic version.